# Distribute lottery tickets randomly from pre-gerenated set in PHP

Tags: php, database, random

I'm looking for an atomic way to pick one ticket from a poll of tickets and give it to someone in PHP. So far I have thought of a few different solutions but I'm not sure how atomic they are (two people must NEVER have the same ticket).

All tickets are pre-generated in the range of 1-N (random numbers as tickets can't be used). The methods I think are viable are:

1) Use a file to store the tickets shuffled and pick the first one and rewrite the file (or pick the last one and only truncate without rewrite). Simplest example:

```
function NextTicket()
{
  $fh = fopen('tickets.txt', 'rw+');
  flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) //hopefully this should prevent parallel access

  $all = explode("\n", stream_get_contents($arq));
  $return = $all[0]; //ticket to be returned

  unset($all[0]);
  rewind($fh);
  ftruncate($fh,0);
  fwrite($fh, implode("\n", $all);
  fclose($fh);

  return $ticket;
}
```

2) Use a sqlite file to hold all tickets and extract a row at a time (supposes shuffled rows inserted).

```
function NextTicket()
{
  $db = new SQLite3('tickets.sqlite');
  $db->exec('BEGIN');
    $res = $db->query('SELECT rowid,TI_NUMBER FROM tickets LIMIT 1');
    $ticket = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    $db->exec('DELETE FROM tickets WHERE rowid='.$ticket['rowid']);
  $db->exec('COMMIT');

  return $ticket['TI_NUMBER'];
}
```

3) Use sqlite as a counter with a single row instead of holding each ticket number in a row (I cannot use this method because the delivery should be random).

```
function NextTicket()
{
  $db = new SQLite3('/tmp/tickets.sqlite');
  $db->exec('BEGIN');
    $res = $db->query('SELECT rowid,TI_NUMBER FROM tickets LIMIT 1');
    $ticket = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    $res = $db->query('UPDATE tickets SET TI_NUMBER=TI_NUMBER+1 WHERE rowid='.$ticket['rowid']);
  $db->exec('COMMIT');

  return $ticket['TI_NUMBER'];
}
```

4) Other approaches? Mysql 5.6 database is also available. Auto increment cannot be used as it's sequential and I need random row from the set. Maybe combining 1 and 3 to get a specific position from inside the shuffled file based in the auto increment.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? How was it solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you need to reshuffle every time for it to be random. Shuffle a few times initially, and whatever order they are in is random and you can just pull them off the top as requested. Think about it this way: you have 30 tickets and someone requests one. They have a 1 in 30 chance of which one they will get. Now fast forward to the last two tickets. Someone requests one, they'll have a 1 in 2 chance of which of those last two they get, but still a 1 in 30 chance of which of the original 30 they will receive. So reshuffling doesn't make it "more random".

Comment: Shuffle happens only once during the generation of the tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give many random tickets, just use mysql table with columns `id, number`. Set N random numbers to it and get+remove first/last. You can use shuffled array from 1 to N as source.

But what if you just will use counter in DB and will give not random tickets? For result it doesn't matter, because winner's number will get with random generator too. Then all will become more simpler. And to hide from users, that numbers are not random, just use encoding function, that will use auto-increment number as argument.

Code for example of encoding function:

```
function encryptNumber($number) {

        $ahphaEncodeTable = [
            0  => 'N', 1  => 'E', 2  => 'D', 3  => 'O',
            4  => 'K', 5  => 'Z', 6  => 'M', 7  => 'R',
            8  => 'L', 9  => 'A'
        ];

        $numEncodeTable = [
            0 => 3, 1 => 6,
            2 => 9, 3 => 0,
            4 => 4, 5 => 8,
            6 => 1, 7 => 7,
            8 => 5, 9 => 2
        ];

        $numbersArr        = array_map('intval', str_split($number));
        $numbersFirstIndex = key($numbersArr);
        $numbersArrKeys    = array_keys($numbersArr);
        $numbersLastIndex  = end($numbersArrKeys);

        $resultHash = '';

        foreach ($numbersArr as $index => $number) {
            if($numbersFirstIndex === $index) {
                $resultHash .= $ahphaEncodeTable[$number];

                if($numbersFirstIndex === $numbersLastIndex) {
                    $resultHash .= mt_rand(0, 9);
                }
            }
            elseif($numbersLastIndex === $index) {
                if($numbersFirstIndex !== $numbersLastIndex) {
                    //insert after first letter in string
                    $resultHash = substr_replace($resultHash, $ahphaEncodeTable[$number], 1, 0);
                }

                $resultHash .= mt_rand(0, 9);
            }
            else {
                $resultHash .= $numEncodeTable[$number];
            }
        }

        return $resultHash;
}
```

Comment: The idea of encoding the tickets sounds like a good way to go, thank you very much. This simplifies the solution to use a single auto increment counter.